# How to secure an API in which only the owner of an article can delete/update that article?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

Suppose I have two entities `User` and `Article` which are having `One-to-Many` relationship.
Now, User `theCoder` created an article - "**How to ask question?**" . Article got saved in `Article` table with foreign key `theCoder`.
Now, another user `theHacker` logged into the application from somewhere and read the "**How to ask question?**" article. Now, he/she tried to perform `delete`/`update` actions on the article, which they are not allowed to. Only the owner of the article can `delete`/`update` the article.

How should I achieve this?

One way is to check the `principle`(logged in user's username) and then compare the user who create that article. If they match, delete/update the post otherwise throw `403 unauthorized`.

But that would be a lot to do. Is there something handy provided by the Spring security?

I looked for it and there is ACL security, but I don't understand if it's the one I am in use of. Nor there are some good articles/blogs/tutorials found on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you mentioned would be the best way in your business environment. ACL would be more work to do then your method. but if you want to try, I think it would help you. [article about spring-security-acl](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl)

Comment: Baeldung materials are great but this particular topic is not clearly explained using a good example.

Comment: @TheCoder i think this article covered your case. Plz check the example with username “hr”. BTW, github address is at the end.